# Do all the planets in our solar system orbit the sun in the same direction and in the same plane?

Tags: orbital-motion, planets, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

Do all the planets in our solar system orbit the sun in the same direction and in the same plane? (as in a flat orbit if you are looking from "above")

Comment: Orbit the sun in same direction meaning? Clockwise, anti-clockwise? Or you mean the same shape?

Comment: This is basic factual information that is easily found.

Answer (score 3):

Close.

And the reason is simple - consider the initial ball of gas and dust that collected into the sun and planets. Imagine the initial velocities are all random, so those particles in orbit are travelling in all directions, spread out over a ball.

Now simply think about it as it moves through time. Eventually everyone going right will hit someone going left. Eventually you are left with the clumps retaining the net angular momentum of the cloud. That will be, by definition, co-planar.

But not perfectly. There is some spread, as you might expect, and at the far reaches of the solar system this process is still ongoing so you get things like Pluto.